# W0223-ADC: ADC input voltage low. ADC output underflow

Tags: simulator, pic, mplab

```
Platform MPLAB X
CPU PIC18F2520
Compiler XC8 v1.38
```

When I execute our project in the simulator the follwing message is flooded in the simulator output window

```
"W0223-ADC: ADC input voltage low.  ADC output underflow"
```

Anyone knows how to get ride of it ?

I guess i have to "stimulate" an AD input but it is hard to understand which one.

Regards Stefan

Comment: Are you enabling the ADC? What is the ADC setup?

Comment: You mean the config bits?
(note, we execute the code successfully in the hardware target and I wanted to just test the simulator to see if it is any good)
ADCON1 = 0b00001101;
#pragma config PBADEN = ON

Regards

Comment: No I mean the SFR values, like ADCON1 :)